# Store large video files in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, content-database, remote-blob-storage, media-streaming, video-richmedia

I have a SharePoint site for one of my clients and it is mainly used for publishing (ECM). In terms of size, the site can be considered as a "small" site as we have overall DB size of 100GB (approx) and a total of 2000 users (not a high traffic site).
So far the site is used for publishing pages only (with associated images and documents) but now the plan is to leverage the SharePoint to host videos too. These videos are near HD quality (~720p) and hundreds of MB in size. I understand that it is not a good idea to host all these videos in an Asset Library(s) even though it is considered as a good option for smaller videos. In addition, to host all these videos, I also would like to get the streaming capability for the hosted videos but that is a secondary objective.

I have few options in front of me but I really do not know the best one to choose.

1. RBS - This seems a good idea because everything resides on the farm and it is not too expensive to add storage. But I am kind of hesitant due to
       the higher operational cost and complexities. Also, no streaming capability.
2. Azure Blob Storage - same thoughts as RBS
3. Azure media services - This seems to be a good
       an idea as it provides both transcoding and streaming for the uploaded videos
4. Host videos externally - Look for a third-party video hosting and streaming
       provider and integrate with SharePoint (just like uploading to a
       YouTube private channel and embedding into SharePoint page, but the
       organization policy do not currently support hosting on YouTube)
5. Setup a separate media server with IIS to host videos, within the farm.

From an on-prem SharePoint 2013 perspective, can anyone of you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/03/29/corporate-youtube-and-video-delivery-via-sharepoint-2013/). Using a streaming media provider (meaning not only keeping the video files but extensively use of them) is always a good idea so look at Azure Media Services. However if your target is only to store files, consider RBS\Azure BLOB.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Streaming is just a secondary objective for me. The prime objective is end user experience, security and lower infrastructure overhead. As of now RBS tends to be best option as it integrates perfectly with the SharePoint and content creators (users) do not need to worry about a new system when it come to uploading their videos.

Comment: Microsoft's RBS would not be an appropriate choice as it is not designed for this scenario. Remember that a CDB using Microsoft's RBS is limited to no greater than 100GB for database + RBS content. Azure Media Services would be the best choice out of the ones you've listed.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I missed that limitation. Still going through the RBS and various use cases.

Comment: I agree with Trevor. After a lot of debate on the same question, we end up with using Media Service. We have created a provider hosted app and my remote solution is using media service in MVC application. It is very close to the architecture here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/steve_fox/2012/08/04/sharepoint-2013-and-windows-azure-media-services/

Comment: @TrevorSeward, I am not sure how to mark your comment as answer. I have decided to go with your suggestion. I have decided to use Azure Media Services and storage to host and stream my video files. A custom App will be developed to provide the user interface on the SharePoint site. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider enabling blob cache (if you haven't already)
It will cache files on the front-end web servers reducing database load.

Details on web.config settings can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261797.aspx